# What is missing in my configuration for Publishing my Sitecore Site Locally?

Tags: iis, sitecore

I have published to my File system: c:/Sites/intranet-local/Website

I have created a website under Sites in IIS: pointing to the above.

I received the following error:

Cannot read configuration file because it exceeds the maximum file size, thus I set up my Registry to increase the size of MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB to 400 or Hex 190.

I restarted my site and I am still getting the same error. 
Is there something else I need to look at.

Note: Sitecore database in NOT local and not installed locally

Sitecore Release 7.2

Comment: Make the size limit really big - like 20 MB - to be sure that the error isn’t telling you exactly what is wrong. FWIW I’ve never had to adjust that setting in 7 years of building Sitecore sites.

Comment: Did you see this https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/27/how-to-fix-cannot-read-configuration-file-because-it-exceeds-the-maximum-file-size/ seems like you might need to add a new key if you are on 64 bit OS. Did you reset IIS or just restart the site?

Comment: Solved it by splitting up the web.config http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/122/getting-started-with-iis-70-configuration/

Comment: I have tried to make the MaxWebConfigFileSizeinKB larger, up to 20MB, no luck. I have split the Web.config into two pieces, still no luck.